# How to build a federated system with CSV dataset with SparkNL library?

Tags: tensorflow-federated, flower, federated-learning, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I am very interested in federated systems and i was trying one of the pre trained multilingual models such as this notebook [Multi_Lingual_Training_and_models](https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp-workshop/blob/master/tutorials/Certification_Trainings/Public/5.2_Multi_Lingual_Training_and_models.ipynb).

I was looking for any tutorials using TFF or Flower frameworks that handle csv datasets.

So could you suggest any tutorials or github repositories to help me do that with TFF or Flower!